# Laravel pusher, /broadcasting/auth:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel, pusher

I clear the cookies, then I log into the account and get the token, as soon as I enter any page where there are sockets I get errors:

> [2020-08-10 17:50:43] local.ERROR: The resource owner or authorization
> server denied the request. {"exception":"[object]
> (League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException(code: 9): The
> resource owner or authorization server denied the request. at
> C:\laragon\www\delivery\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Exception\OAuthServerException.php:243)
> [stacktrace]
> #0 C:\laragon\www\delivery\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\AuthorizationValidators\BearerTokenValidator.php(88):
> League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::accessDenied('The
> JWT string ...', NULL, Object(InvalidArgumentException))

> [previous exception] [object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The
> JWT string must have two dots at

> local.ERROR: Route [login] not defined. {"exception":"[object]
> (Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException(code:
> 0): Route [login] not defined. at
> C:\laragon\www\delivery\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:420)
> [stacktrace]

If I reload the page, the errors disappear forever. These errors appear only the first time when you get to a page where sockets are used, I use vue js on the frontend. For authentication I am using laravel passport.

local settings of my pusher

```
indow.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
    auth:{
        headers:{
            Authorization:'Bearer ' + Cookies.get('access_token'),
        },
    },
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    encrypted:false,
    forceTLS: false,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

The production has a secure connection, the error exists.

For authentication I use laravel passport

Comment: Have you checked the request sent to your server?  is the authorization header correctly sent to the server?

Comment: Yes, 
I fixed this by adding the initialization of the pusher to the mounted component's hook, before that my pusher was initialized on any page, regardless of whether the user was logged in or not, because when going to the login page, the pusher was initialized with an undefined token because the user was not logged in system.

Answer (score 0):

The error message reads: `Route [login] not defined`

... this means that you lack the default `Auth::routes()`.

Run `php artisan ui vue --auth` for a fresh app.